# ¿Cuál es la alternativa en español a "Black Friday"?

Tags: traducción, uso-de-palabras, expresiones, rae, extranjerismos

Cuando llegó la actualización 23.1 del DLE, en diciembre de 2017, la nota de prensa en la web de la RAE [dice lo siguiente](http://www.rae.es/noticias/la-rae-presenta-la-primera-actualizacion-de-la-23a-edicion-de-su-dle) acerca del uso de anglicismos:

> Durante la rueda de prensa, el director de la RAE ha aprovechado para recordar que, si bien «la Academia no está cerrada a la incorporación de extranjerismos, sí nos preocupa la reiteración excesiva del uso de palabras en inglés sin que sea necesario». Si en 1713, en el año fundacional de la corporación, los primeros académicos se enfrentaron a un problema similar con los galicismos, actualmente se da, de forma más intensa, con el inglés.
>
> A continuación, Darío Villanueva ha ofrecido varios ejemplos del uso innecesario de anglicismos por tener un equivalente en español: *black friday, take away, save the date, dress code, prime time, streaming, product manager, community manager*, etcétera.

Puedo estar más o menos de acuerdo con este artículo, e incluso me puedo imaginar cuáles son las propuestas de la RAE para la mayoría de estos términos, pero hay uno que me desconcierta: si yo digo "viernes negro", a mí lo que se me viene a la cabeza no es un día de descuentos, sino que ha sucedido una tragedia terrible.

> **[negro](http://dle.rae.es/?id=QN0nGts)**
>
> 13. adj. Infeliz, infausto y desventurado.

Posiblemente sea la falta de costumbre. A fin de cuentas, [hay historias que cuentan](http://canalhistoria.es/blog/el-origen-del-black-friday/) que el término hace alusión a que

> [...] el viernes 24 de septiembre de 1869, dos implacables financieros de Wall Street, Jay Gould y Jim Fisk, tras un intenso trabajo por conseguir grandes beneficios, fracasaron en su empeño, y el mercado entró en bancarrota.

También se dice que

> [...] tiene que ver con el papel de los pequeños comercios en el mercado. La tradición cuenta que, tras un año entero de pérdidas (es decir, números rojos), por fin, tras el día de Acción de Gracias, llegaba la época navideña, día a partir del cual comenzaban los beneficios, y con ellos, en lugar de números rojos, se producían “números negros”.

Así pues, parece que sí, que "viernes negro" podría ser una opción válida pero por la costumbre, yo denomino a ese día el "black friday", y con ese término es como yo entiendo el día especial de rebajas.

Así pues, preguntas:

- ¿Es "viernes negro" el término que quiere la RAE que usemos para llamar al "black friday"? Sí, el artículo que enlazo usa ese término, pero quería saber si la RAE lo confirma como adaptación válida.
- ¿Se usa el término "viernes negro" de forma común en algún país hispanohablante?
- En textos escritos en español, ¿qué proporción de casos se dan actualmente de "black friday" frente a "viernes negro" (u otras alternativas)?

Comment: @walen y curiosamente, [el artículo de la Wikipedia del "Black Friday"](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viernes_negro_(compras)) usa la traducción.

Comment: Yo usaría "viernes negro" que es la traducción directa. Quizá en otros casos (como con "Acción de Gracias" en lugar de por ejemplo "Dando gracias" para _Thanksgiving_) favorecería una traducción menos literal, pero en este caso no veo problema (y la ventaja en usar algo que no sea "viernes negro" habría que discutirla, según lo que se propusiese).

Comment: La Wikipedia en español es muy militante en el uso de la terminología castellana, incluso en casos en que nadie la utiliza. Por ejemplo, todos los pueblos de España tienen el nombre en castellano en su artículo, aunque hoy día esté completamente en desuso (me refiero a pueblos de lugares con lengua cooficial, claro). Por tanto, el hecho de que este artículo se llame *Viernes Negro* no es indicativo de nada.

Comment: @Gorpik - Buena observación. // En Alemania usan *Black Friday* pronunciado un poco a la alemana.  Esto me parece bien, porque el concepto en sí es tan ajeno a la cultura tradicional de los países que no sean EEUU.

Comment: También para un angloparlante podría confundir porque negro en inglés tiene un mal sentido.  En este caso, negro refiere al color de la tinta del contador que queda en rojo hasta el negocio gane dinero.  Supuestamente en "viernes negro" el negocio llega a tener ganancia.  La tinta del contador ya no es roja, sino negra.

Answer (score 3):

## Viernes negro

En la historia de muchos países, han existido eventos políticos o económicos que por su naturaleza negativa han sido llamados **viernes negro**. Es posible que el primer evento de esta naturaleza haya sido a consecuencia de los conflictos bélicos en Europa a finales del s.XIX que causo un retiro general de inversiones y una consecuente escasez de crédito. Este evento fue conocido en Inglaterra como **viernes negro** (11 de mayo de 1866) y causó quiebras en España así como efectos en otros países incluyendo América.

Después de este evento, hay otros sucesos que se han bautizado como **viernes negro**

- 1869, crisis de Nueva York
- 1983, devaluación del bolivar
- 1987, represión política de Panamá
- 2001, crisis en Argentina

Ahora bien, según el sitio del history channel, entre otras [historias](https://www.history.com/news/whats-the-real-history-of-black-friday), se destaca el supuesto de que en los años 50, la policía de Filadelphia en los EE.UU. llamaba **Black Friday** al día despues de *acción de gracias*. En este día, hordas de compradores saturaban las calles de la cuidad para anticiparse al juego de fútbol americano entre los representantes de las academias de la armada y la marina. Debido a la connotación negativa de la expresión **Black Friday**, los comerciantes de la cuidad trataron de cambiar el término a **Big Friday** con resultados nulos.

---

## El buen fin

En México, en el año 2011 se lanzó una campaña similar al **black friday**. El evento se ha estado llevando a cabo de manera anual y se denomina **El buen fin**.

---

Solo quiero hacer unos comentarios al respecto:

- La palabra **negro** siempre tiene un sentido negativo y, por consecuencia, **viernes negro** es usado como un evento desafortunado; de la misma manera que **rojo** también tiene el sentido de un evento donde hubo derramamiento de sangre.
- Aún cuando al escuchar **viernes negro**, en nuestra mente, es asociado de manera natural con algún evento desafortunado por la acepción correspondiente de la palabra **negro**; el término es ampliamente conocido como la campaña de ventas en los EEUU.
- En un ámbito local, tanto para los que se lanzan de compras ese día desde la madrugada como para los compradores normales, el **Black Friday** es también sinónimo de un día de caos donde hay mucho tráfico, aglomeración de personas, grandes tiempos de espera para hecer pagos en los comercios y en general un aumento del estrés general. Por este motivo, las conotaciones negativas también son relevantes.
- El término **el buen fin** no es la castellanización (en este caso mexicanización) de **black friday**. Aunque **El buen fin** esta inspirado en el **black friday**, es un evento distinto. En mi opinión, simplemente los encargados de la campaña quisieron evitar todas las connotaciones negativas de la palabra **black** y la sustituyeron por una palabra positiva; en este caso: **buen**.
- En cuanto al término encontrado en RAE: aún cuando el razonamiento que expresas en tu pregunta es válido, el hecho de que **black** y **friday** tienen equivalentes directos en español me hace pensar que es muy difícil elegir un conjunto de palabras distinto sin entrar en controversias o ambigüedades.

Comment: Cierto, me refería a "en español", y no "de España". He modificado la pregunta para que quede más claro.

Comment: No es el mismo día. En la mayoría de los casos hay una semana de diferencia pero esto es casualidad. El black friday tiene lugar el día siguiente a thanksgiving y el buen fin es el fin de semana anterior al 20 de noviembre.

Comment: Tienes razón @walen. Sin embargo, no lo propongo como como una traducción; en cambio, intento ilustrar con el ejemplo en que un grupo de comerciantes mexicanos intentaron adaptar una idea extranjera tomando en cuenta el contexto cultural y de lenguaje. En la aclaración de la RAE, se mencionan otros anglicismos; sin embargo solo black friday tiene acepciones casi opuestas. Estamos de acuerdo que denominar viernes negro a un evento nefasto no está sometido a discusión; es cuando se refiere a la campaña de ventas en los EEUU donde encontramos la controversia.

Answer (score 3):

Personalmente **no veo motivo para traducirlo**: **es una fecha inventada por los estadounidenses, un evento con nombre propio**. Y los nombres propios, en principio, no hay por qué traducirlos.

<sub>Puede argumentarse que los nombres de festividades siempre los traducimos: Acción de Gracias, Día de San Patricio... pero yo lo veo más como un tema de elección personal.</sub>

Esto de inventarse fechas no es nada raro. Aquí en España, muchas franquicias hacen lo mismo: inventarse "eventos" en los que poder aplicar descuentos *legalmente* (ver siguiente párrafo). Algunos nombres os sonarán: los *Días de Oro*, la *Semana de la Moda*, los *Días sin IVA*, los *Martes Locos*...

Lo de *legalmente* viene porque la legislación española no permite usar la palabra "rebajas" fuera de las fechas establecidas para ello (verano y enero). Lo cual es un fastidio, porque seguramente lo mejor sería llamar al Black Friday "Rebajas de Noviembre" pero, como digo, al menos en España, no es legal.

Entonces, si queremos buscar un nombre en español que funcione en todos los países, solo con echar un vistazo a la [página de desambiguación de la Wikipedia para "Viernes Negro"](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viernes_Negro) queda claro que tal expresión no sería desde luego la más acertada para atraer clientes a un comercio. Las connotaciones de "[día] negro" en español son, como dices, demasiado negativas (consultas por Lunes Negro, Martes Negro, etc. ofrecen resultados similares).

Como alternativas algo menos macabras, podríamos inventarnos, por ejemplo, "Viernes Loco", "Super Viernes"... Seguramente alguien que haya estudiado *marketing* pueda ofrecer mejores ideas :D
Pero todas ellas fallarán en una cosa, y es que pierden la publicidad gratuita que conlleva llamar al evento igual que hacen en Estados Unidos. Cosas del mundo globalizado.